# How to detect OS my Asp.Net Core app is running on?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an Asp.Net Core 1.0.0 app that runs on both Linux and Windows. In the app I need to upload files and save them in `wwwroot` subfolders. I get `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` and specify a subfolder. It works fine on Windows but not on Linux because of paths. Window's `\` of course is not going to work. So how can I detect whether my app is running on Windows or Linux from controller and choose an appropriate path delimiter?

Comment: If you do want to know the OS, `RuntimeInformation` or `Environment` can be used https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9729

Comment: as DavidG mentioned, you can abstract-out knowing if its "/" or "\" by using Path methods to give you directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than this, you should use `Path.Combine` to generate directory names. For example:

```
var root = env.WebRootPath;
var myDirectory = Path.Combine(root, "subdirectory");
```

Comment: Thank you! It works great! I didn't know of `Path` class and its features

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/` on both Windows and Linux